# Contradiction about thermodynamic system

Tags: thermodynamics

While watching this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL2U3P7-CoI&list=PLp-8j6_XqvKQcI3w1QXKaxM6whld1O_yy&index=11%5D),

**Thermodynamic system** is defined as *a macroscopic region of the continuous  medium, always formed by the same collection of continuous matter (material volume). It can be: Isolated system or an open system(that can exchange matter and heat)*.

**How come the thermodynamic system is always formed by the same collection of continuous matter while it can be an open system?**

Comment: It is a contradiction. Actually the thermodynamic system need not consist of the same matter, but it you must be able to draw an imaginary border, which defines inside and outside of the system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_system. Quote: "A wall of a thermodynamic system may be purely notional, when it is described as being 'permeable' to all matter, all radiation, and all forces"

Comment: When exchanging matters, it exchanges with the surrounding only the same type of materials, e,g, the same gas molecules.